# Scrapy Get value of javascript attribute

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to get value of javascript which is you can see below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//media.flixfacts.com/js/loader.js" data-flix-distributor="7148" data-flix-language="tr" data-flix-brand="lg" data-flix-ean="8806087586213" data-flix-sku="1162559" data-flix-inpage="flix-inpage"></script>
```

I Tried this but its not worked.

```
ean = response.xpath('/html/head/script[25]/@data-flix-ean').extract_first()
```

Comment: Where's the page you're trying to scrape? We have no way to know what's wrong with your XPath if we can't see the page source.

Comment: I am just trying to get an attribute from this tag. I'm already getting already this tag.

 <script type="text/javascript" src="//media.flixfacts.com/js/loader.js" data-flix-distributor="7148" data-flix-language="tr" data-flix-brand="lg" data-flix-ean="8806087586213" data-flix-sku="1162559" data-flix-inpage="flix-inpage"></script>

But I need the get data-flix-ean attribute

Comment: ...what is the url of the page you are trying to scrape. Like how the url of this page is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198101/scrapy-get-value-of-javascript-attribute

Comment: @YPCrumble http://www.mediamarkt.com.tr/tr/product/_lg-49uh850v-49-in%C3%A7-124-cm-ekran-dahili-uydu-al%C4%B1c%C4%B1l%C4%B1-4k-3d-smart-led-tv-1162559.html this is url

Comment: any help or suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the source code for that page you can find the following piece of code:

```
<script>
var sFlix = document.createElement('script');
    sFlix.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    sFlix.setAttribute('src', '//media.flixfacts.com/js/loader.js');
    sFlix.setAttribute('data-flix-distributor', '7148');
    sFlix.setAttribute('data-flix-language', 'tr');
    sFlix.setAttribute('data-flix-brand', Storm.DataLayer.data.user.productBrand.toLowerCase());
    sFlix.setAttribute('data-flix-ean', Storm.DataLayer.data.user.ean);
    sFlix.setAttribute('data-flix-sku', Storm.DataLayer.data.user.productId);
    sFlix.setAttribute('data-flix-inpage', 'flix-inpage');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(sFlix);
    setTimeout(function(){ $(document).trigger('fee.fgrid_refresh'); }, 2000);
    setTimeout(function(){ $(document).trigger('fee.fgrid_refresh'); }, 4000);
    setTimeout(function(){ $(document).trigger('fee.fgrid_refresh'); }, 6000);
    setTimeout(function(){ $(document).trigger('fee.fgrid_refresh'); }, 20000);
    $('#flix-inpage').load(function() {
    $(document).trigger('fee.fgrid_refresh');
    }); 
    setTimeout(function(){ $(document).trigger('fee.fgrid_refresh'); }, 40000);
</script>
```

which means the `script` tag you are looking for is not actually in the received response, it's created dynamically. In order to extract the information you need, you should query the source of the `data-flix-ean` attribute, the `Storm.DataLayer` object:

`response.xpath('/html/head/script/text()').re(r"Storm.DataLayer.put\('ean','(.*)'\);")`